# nginx + php-fpm cant run script more than 50 sec

Tags: nginx, php

there is a script which runs more than 50sec, but after 50 sec a got "504 Gateway Time-out".

My fpm pool config

```
[oscommerce]
listen = /srv/www/oscommerce/run/runphp53.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = oscommerce
listen.group = oscommerce
listen.mode = 0666
user = oscommerce
group = oscommerce
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 16
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 16

catch_workers_output = yes

request_terminate_timeout = 600

php_admin_value[error_log] = /srv/www/oscommerce/log/php-fpm53.error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 100M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 100M
php_admin_value[default_socket_timeout] = 600
php_admin_value[mysql.connect_timeout] = 600
php_admin_value[session.use_only_cookies] = 0
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = Europe/Moscow


php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 600
php_admin_value[max_input_time] = 600
php_admin_value[display_errors] = On
php_admin_value[display_startup_errors] = On
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL
```

and my vhost config

```
server {
        server_name ...;
        root /srv/www/oscommerce/httpdocs;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        client_header_timeout 300s;
        client_body_timeout 300s;
        send_timeout 300s;

        error_log /srv/www/oscommerce/log/error.log;
        access_log /srv/www/oscommerce/log/access.log;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|js|swf)$ {
                root /srv/www/oscommerce/httpdocs;
        }

        location / {
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                #proxy_read_timeout 600s;
                #proxy_connect_timeout 600s;

                #fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
                #fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
                #fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/srv/www/oscommerce/run/runphp53.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $uri;  #necessary for URL rewrite

                fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        }
}
```

There is no serious error.

I lost 5 days to solve this issue, but there is no result.
any ideas?

Comment: You're sure it's a timeout on the server side and not something like an out of memory error leading to the 504?

Comment: maybe, but I havent got any ide where to look, in which log etc.

Comment: Nothing in the Nginx log?  Or maybe watch `top` when the script is running - that may help identify whether or not this is a memory problem.

Comment: Can you post the script?